Http 429 is not returnable in status code from C# ASP.NET Core Web API
[Route("{route}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    var test = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);
    return test;
}

Implementing an ASP.NET Core Web API controller. The intention is to return HTTP 429.
However, the 429 is returned in the response body but the actual response is HTTP 200
Example response from Postman below
{
    "Version": "1.1",
    "Content": {
        "Headers": []
    },
    "StatusCode": 429,
    "ReasonPhrase": "Too Many Requests",
    "Headers": [],
    "TrailingHeaders": [],
    "RequestMessage": null,
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": false
}


Any ideas how to fix this please?
I want the response in Postman to have a HTTP 429 status code.
Ideally, my expectation is that both response body and response header should be containing HTTP 429 (here, the response payload status is 429 but the response header contains 200)

Probably this answer from Correct way to return HttpResponseMessage as IActionResult in .Net Core 2.2 may helps...

This is because you are creating your own HttpResponseMessage, which is totally wrong - it's not how ASP.NET HTTP pipeline works. It does not pick just randomly created HTTP messages. That's why you don't see the results you expect.
The HTTP response that will be returned can be referenced through HttpContext.Response (HttpContext is property that is inherited from ControllerBase), and you can set its property StatusCode - this will take effect you expect.
The easiest solution is:
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests;

Returning additional data
To return additional data, you can set the body of the HTTP response directly on HttpContext.Response, but that wouldn't look well. Instead, you should set return type of the endpoint method to IActionResult and then you can leverage ObjectResult class, as follows:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests;
    return new ObjectResult(new { AnyData = "any data" });
}


Thanks @Michal Turczyn. This solves the issue.

I've used my own return type.
e.g. 1public async Task<MyReturnType> Post([FromBody] dynamic data)
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.TooMayRequests
return new MyReturnType{}


I want the POSTMAN response to have a HTTP 429 here.

You can try following code snippet to specify a statusCode and value:
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status429TooManyRequests, "Too Many Requests");


Thanks @Fei Han. However, this means that I have to change the response type of the method.

What is the correct way of handling this? Sometimes, we would want to return some additional data (e.g. telemetry data). So, having 'ObjectType' as the response param, may not work for all cases. Would be happy to know the industry standard here.

You can try to modify the action to return IActionResult like this public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] dynamic data) and construct different object result in action code logic based on your requirement.

Instead of returning HttpResponseMessage, you might want to use IActionResult or ActionResult (if you're using ASP.NET Core) for more straightforward handling of HTTP responses:
[Route("{route}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);
}

